# How do i change the color and font-family of the input form placeholder?

Tags: html, css, forms

I tried by changing color in body, didn't work well

Also, i tried doing instead of using `body{` , using `placeholder {` , didn't work either

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder..." />
```

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: Is the php tag relevant?

Answer (score 0):

placeholder can be accessed by `::placeholder` pseudo class.

So, if your input element's id is `testinput` then your css can be

```
#testinput::placeholder {
   color: blue;
   font-family: Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.
Style the placeholder with the non-standard ::placeholder selector.

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: red;
}
```

You have more info here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp